# Ambari and Spark cant start from CLI

Tags: hadoop

From the Ambari GUI we can not start the Spark service. So we want to start it by command line as the following:

```
[spark@mas01 spark2]$ ./sbin/start-thriftserver.sh --master yarn-client --executor-memory 512m --hiveconf hive.server2.thrift.port=10015
starting org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.HiveThriftServer2, logging to /var/log/spark2/spark-spark-org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.HiveThriftServer2-1-master01.octopus9.com.out
```

But from the log we get the error:

> Warning: Master yarn-client is deprecated since 2.0. Please use master
>   "yarn" with specified deploy mode instead.

Please advice what is wrong with the syntax?

```
[spark@mas01 spark2]$ more /var/log/spark2/spark-spark-org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.HiveThriftServer2-1-master01.octopus9.com.out
Spark Command: /usr/jdk64/jdk1.8.0_112/bin/java -Dhdp.version=2.6.0.3-8 -cp /usr/hdp/2.6.0.3-8/spark2/conf/:/usr/hdp/2.6.0.3-8/spark2/jars/*:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/conf/ -Xmx10000m org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit --master yarn-client --class org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.HiveThriftServer2 --name Thrift JDBC/ODBC Server --executor-memory 512m spark-internal -- hiveconf hive.server2.thrift.port=10015
========================================
Warning: Master yarn-client is deprecated since 2.0. Please use master "yarn" with specified deploy mode instead.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before Spark 2.0.0, it was possible to use `yarn-client` or `yarn-cluster` and which is now deprecated. When you use the deprecated master URLs, you will get the mentioned warning.

The only proper master URL is now `yarn`, e.g. `./bin/spark-submit --master yarn ...`. You can then use `--deploy-mode` to choose between  Spark `client` (default) or Spark `cluster` modes.